# How do you correctly handle redirection in FOR loop in one line of command?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to output the file cat.txt's content and save them in another text file using FOR /F loop ( in one line of command of standard cmd shell.)

for example, here is the source file.

```
# content of cat.txt:
meow
meo
me
m
```

after use this command, I've got some unintended result:

`FOR /F "tokens=*" %G in (cat.txt) DO echo %G > D:\copy-cat.txt`

```
# I got output:
meow > D:\copy-cat.txt
meo > D:\copy-cat.txt
me > D:\copy-cat.txt
m > D:\copy-cat.txt
```

I understand in this scenario, the redirection is being affected by echo, hence recognized as string and echoed out.

**Question: How do I semantically separate the code so that I can redirect all the content that were written to stdout into D:\copy-cat.txt?**

*Note: as you can see by %G, I need to write this directly in commandline, not in a batch script.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
>copy-cat.txt (FOR /F "delims=" %G in (cat.txt) DO @echo %G)
```

- Instead of redirecting each output line, redirect the full `for` output
- To avoid the inclusion of the `echo` command itself, use prefix the command with `@` to not echo the `echo` (single command `echo off`)